# Does a finite, strongly-connected, labeled digraph with no non-trivial automorphism always have a unique path?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Assume that a digraph is finite and strongly connected, and that all edges and vertices bear labels from some set. Let $f(v)$ be the label of vertex $v$, and $f(e)$ be the label of edge $e$. Say that a path $v=(v_1, e_1, v_2, e_2, ... , e_k, v_{k+1})$ is not unique if there exists a *distinct* path $v'=(v_1', e_1', v_2', e_2', ... , e_k', v_{k+1}')$ (distinct meaning $v'≠v$) with matching labels, i.e., such that $f(v_i)=f(v_i')$ for $i=1...k+1$ and $f(e_i)=f(e_i')$ for $i=1...k$. A path is *unique* if there is no distinct path with matching labels.

It's obvious that a graph with a unique path has no non-trivial automorphism (i.e., a non-trivial mapping that preserves labels). Is the converse true? That is, does a finite labeled digraph with no non-trivial automorphism always have a unique path? If the answer is not known, are there any interesting results relevant to this question?

Comment: @bof Sorry for the delete. I'll be sure to edit in the future. 
Looking at your examples, I realized I left out a condition. The digraph should be strongly connected. (I'll add that to the question.)

Comment: You say it's obvious that a (strongly connected finite di-) graph with a unique path has no non-trivial automorphism. What about the digraph with vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ and edges $e_1=v_1v_2,e_2=v_2v_3,e_3=v_2v_4,e_4=v_3v_1,e_5=v_4v_1$, with $e_1$ labeled $A$ and everything else labeled $B$? It seems to me that it's finite and strongly connected, and $v=(v_1,e_1,v_2)$ is a unique path, and there is a non-trivial automorphism which swaps $v_3$ and $v_4$. What am I missing?

Comment: By the way, it seems to me you would lose nothing by assuming that only the edges are labeled, as the vertex labels could be encoded in the edge labels. Is that right?

Comment: What about the digraph with vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5$ and edges $v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v_4,v_4v_5,v_5v_1,v_1v_3$ (a directed $5$-cycle plus a directed chord), and all labels the same. It has no non-trivial automorphism; does it have a unique path? What do you mean by "path"? Is it a simple path, or can a path repeat vertices and edges?

Comment: @bof "you would lose nothing by assuming that only the edges are labeled, as the vertex labels could be encoded in the edge labels" → yes, that seems right.

Regarding the 5-cycle example: It has no unique path because all paths have the same labels, and thus for any path of length $k$, there is distinct path with matching labels. The path doesn't have to be simple. However, this example has the automorphism  $v1$ → $v2$, $v2$ → $v3$ ... $v5$ → $v1$. That is,  the labels of any arbitrary path match the labels of the image path.

Comment: In the 5-cycle, every bijection from $V$ to $V$ is an automorphism in the sense I'm using (I see now it's kind of idiosyncratic). What I mean is a bijection $m$ on $V$, so that $f(v) = f(m(v))$ and $f(e)=f(m(e))$ for all $v$ and $e$. It's looser than the usual notion of automorphism.

Comment: Another way to express it: Assume a finite, strongly-connected, labeled graph, and whenever vertices bear the same label, merge them all into a single vertex. Maintain the edge relations as you do this, but eliminate duplicates. The 5-cycle with chord becomes a single vertex $v$ with edge $vv$, both bearing the same label. (The original and the reduced graph are "label isomorphic" so to speak.) $vv$ is now a unique path. That's my admittedly muddled intuition. I'll think about it more.

Comment: In the alleged automorphism $v_1\to v_2$, $v_2\to v_3$, $v_3\to v_4$, $v_4\to v_5$, $v_5\to v_1$, what happens to the edge $v_1\to v_3$? Oh, I see you have an unusual definition of "automorphism". Which I'm not sure I understand. If $m$ is a bijection on $V$, then what does $m(e)$ mean?

Comment: @bof There is no image of the edge $v_1$ → $v_3$, but it doesn't matter because the entire graph is equivalent (from the perspective of labels), to the graph with one vertex $v$, one edge $vv$, and $f(v)=f(vv)=L$. Assume two graphs $G$ and $G'$. The only info you can obtain from a graph is the labels. The graph tells you the label of its current vertex. You supply an edge label. It traverses that edge, and gives you the label of the attained vertex. You can test like this along any path. $G$ and $G'$ are "isomorphic" in my intended sense if they can't be distinguished by such testing.

Comment: One definition I was groping for: Let $G=(V,E)$. Each vertex has a label $a(v)$, and each edge has a label $b(uv)$. $G$ has a *label automorphism* if there is a permutation $p$ such that $a(v)=a(p(v))$ for all $v$, and whenever $uv \in E$, then $p(u)p(v) \in E$ and $b(uv)=b(p(u)p(v))$. I see now this is stronger than regular automorphism, and reduces to it when all the labels are the same.

Comment: Other definition: Define the *reduction* of $G$. Vertices of the reduction are, for all vertex labels $a$, $v_a = \{ v \in V  |  a(v)=a \}$. There is an edge in the reduction, $v_av_b$ with $b(v_av_b)=b$, iff there are $v, u \in V$ such that $a(v)=a$, $a(u)=b$ and $b(vu)=b$. Say that two graphs are *reduction-equivalent* if they have the same reduction. My muddled intuition was that reduction removes label automorphisms, or that reductions always have a unique path. I'll think about it more. It's the properties of reductions that I'm interested in. Thanks for your thoughts.